# Slow OracleDataReader in c# code for retrieving 50 records in 9 seconds

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I have an Oracle database with several tables and by using the OracleDataReader from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client namespace it is very slow in reading any of the tables. The test table has 70 fields and 50 records approx.

This is just a test table, because I have tables with 200,000 records and it is very slow.

Based on the following code, I read approx. 50 records with 70 fields in 9 seconds. It seems that apparently the record is retrieved fast enough, but the problem is in the loop for obtaining field values. I have tested with several servers hosted on Windows and on Linux and it is the same problem. Any advice ? Thanks.

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));"+ "User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

conn.Open();

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();   // measure time
int oid = 5;                
// now read several records from a one to many table with approx. 70 fields
sql = String.Format(@"select * FROM ""CamposAdicionales"" where ""TablaAdicional"" = {0}", oid);
cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
int recordCount = 0;
sw.Start();
using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // try to optimize defining fetch size
    reader.FetchSize = reader.RowSize * 1000;
    object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            values[i] = reader.GetValue(i);
        }
        recordCount++;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
textBox1.Text = String.Format("GetValue(): Records read : {0}, time (ms) : {1}", recordCount, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) + Environment.NewLine;
```

TablasAdicionales (master table) has 18 records
CamposAdicionales (detail table) has 257 records

This is a dump from SQL Developer (sorry if this does not belong here)...

```
ALTER TABLE "TablasAdicionales"
ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_C006990 PRIMARY KEY 
(
  OID 
)
USING INDEX SYS_C006990
ENABLECREATE TABLE "TablasAdicionales" 
(
  OID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, "IsLayer" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "ZOrder" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "Name" NVARCHAR2(80) 
, "DisplayName" NVARCHAR2(255) 
, "GroupName" NVARCHAR2(30) 
, "ShowInMenu" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "SearchInAllColumns" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "TablaExterna" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "IsMasterLayer" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "OptimisticLockField" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "GCRecord" NUMBER(*, 0) 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLELCREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C006990 ON "TablasAdicionales" (OID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL
CREATE INDEX "iGCRecord_TablasAdicionales" ON "TablasAdicionales" ("GCRecord" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL
CREATE INDEX "iTablaExterna_TablasA_058F6841" ON "TablasAdicionales" ("TablaExterna" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLELALTER TABLE "TablasAdicionales"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_TablasAdicionales__15E489A2" FOREIGN KEY
(
  "TablaExterna" 
)
REFERENCES "TablaExterna"
(
  OID 
)
ENABLE

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C006990 ON "TablasAdicionales" (OID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL

CREATE INDEX "iGCRecord_TablasAdicionales" ON "TablasAdicionales" ("GCRecord" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL

CREATE INDEX "iTablaExterna_TablasA_058F6841" ON "TablasAdicionales" ("TablaExterna" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL


ALTER TABLE "CamposAdicionales"
ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_C006992 PRIMARY KEY 
(
  OID 
)
USING INDEX SYS_C006992
ENABLECREATE TABLE "CamposAdicionales" 
(
  OID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, "TablaAdicional" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "Name" NVARCHAR2(128) 
, "Type" NVARCHAR2(128) 
, "UIShowAsMasterTable" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "VisibleIndex" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "Size" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "Nullable" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "DisplayName" NVARCHAR2(128) 
, "Description" NCLOB 
, "Tooltip" NVARCHAR2(250) 
, "IsUniqueValue" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "DisplayFormat" NVARCHAR2(128) 
, "DisplayFormatType" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "RelationType" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "UIShowInTooltip" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "LookupEditorShowAutoFilterRow" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "LookupEditorUseServerMode" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "AssociationName" NVARCHAR2(255) 
, "Aggregated" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "PictureSizeMode" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "IsLookupEditorCaption" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "ShowInLookupEditor" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "LookupEditorIndex" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "Indexed" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "Delayed" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "NonPersistent" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "IsAutoGenerate" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "UseDropDownEditor" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "UseDropDownEditorInLayout" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "PopupFormWidth" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "PopupFormHeight" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "EditorType" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "SpinEditorMinValue" FLOAT(126) 
, "SpinEditorMaxValue" FLOAT(126) 
, "MaskAutoCompleteType" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "MaskBeepOnError" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "MaskEditMask" NVARCHAR2(128) 
, "MaskIgnoreMaskBlank" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "MaskType" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "MaskPlaceHolder" NCHAR(1) 
, "MaskSaveLiteral" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "MaskShowPlaceHolders" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "UseMaskAsDisplayFormat" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "ImageListSmallSize" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "ImageListLargeSize" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "DefaultValue" NVARCHAR2(255) 
, "IsPrimaryKey" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "FindIncluded" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "FilterIncluded" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "IsImagesCollection" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "ImageStorage" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "IsSandBox" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "FtpIsPassiveMode" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "FtpUserName" NVARCHAR2(60) 
, "FtpPassword" NVARCHAR2(60) 
, "IsLink2LayerField" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "Link2LayerName" NVARCHAR2(80) 
, "Link2LayerFieldName" NVARCHAR2(128) 
, "IsExternalField" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "NameExternalField" NVARCHAR2(80) 
, "ExternalFieldType" NVARCHAR2(20) 
, "IsExternalFieldNullable" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "FullTextSearch" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "Required" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "EnabledFormula" NCLOB 
, "IsContentsCollection" NUMBER(1, 0) 
, "DocsStorage" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "DescripcionContenido" NVARCHAR2(30) 
, "ContentFooterExpression" NCLOB 
, "OptimisticLockField" NUMBER(*, 0) 
, "GCRecord" NUMBER(*, 0) 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL 
LOB ("Description") STORE AS SYS_LOB0000020066C00010$$ 
( 
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW 
  CHUNK 8192 
  RETENTION 
  NOCACHE 
  LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE LASM 
  STORAGE 
  ( 
    INITIAL 5242880 
    NEXT 5242880 
    MINEXTENTS 1 
    MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
    PCTINCREASE 0 
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
  )  
)   
LOB ("EnabledFormula") STORE AS SYS_LOB0000020066C00066$$ 
( 
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW 
  CHUNK 8192 
  RETENTION 
  NOCACHE 
  LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE LASM 
  STORAGE 
  ( 
    INITIAL 5242880 
    NEXT 5242880 
    MINEXTENTS 1 
    MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
    PCTINCREASE 0 
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
  )  
)   
LOB ("ContentFooterExpression") STORE AS SYS_LOB0000020066C00070$$ 
( 
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW 
  CHUNK 8192 
  RETENTION 
  NOCACHE 
  LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE LASM 
  STORAGE 
  ( 
    INITIAL 5242880 
    NEXT 5242880 
    MINEXTENTS 1 
    MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
    PCTINCREASE 0 
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
  )  
)CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C006992 ON "CamposAdicionales" (OID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL
CREATE INDEX "iGCRecord_CamposAdicionales" ON "CamposAdicionales" ("GCRecord" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL
CREATE INDEX "iTablaAdicional_Campo_124AB511" ON "CamposAdicionales" ("TablaAdicional" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLELALTER TABLE "CamposAdicionales"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_CamposAdicionales__78737865" FOREIGN KEY
(
  "TablaAdicional" 
)
REFERENCES "TablasAdicionales"
(
  OID 
)
ENABLE

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C006992 ON "CamposAdicionales" (OID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL

CREATE INDEX "iGCRecord_CamposAdicionales" ON "CamposAdicionales" ("GCRecord" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL

CREATE INDEX "iTablaAdicional_Campo_124AB511" ON "CamposAdicionales" ("TablaAdicional" ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE LASM 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 5242880 
  NEXT 5242880 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL
```

explain plan for (select * from "CamposAdicionales" where "TablaAdicional" = 5) ...

```
Plan hash value: 1715040447

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                                |    48 |   402K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CamposAdicionales              |    48 |   402K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | iTablaAdicional_Campo_124AB511 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("TablaAdicional"=5)

Note
-----
```

Comment: How long does it take to run the query via something like SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, or TOAD?  The query isn't going to be executed when you call `ExecuteReader`, it is going to be executed (in parts) as you fetch data.  My first guess would be that the query runs for 9 seconds and returns 50 rows.

Comment: You are completely right !. I tested with SQL Developer and it takes 9 seconds to complete the query. Of course, the first record appears instantly on the query results window but you can see that the following records are retrieved very slowly and after 9 seconds the query is completed. For practical uses it is very slow. Do you have an idea how this slow response time can be changed ?

Comment: Further guessing, I'd speculate that there is no index on `TablaAdicional` so Oracle has to do a full table scan (or full scan some other index that has `TablaAdicional` but not as the leading column) which often results in a few rows being returned quickly (because they happen to be found at the beginning of the scan) and others that are returned much later.  A single column index on `TablaAdicional` would be ideal for that query.  Going forward, I'd also strongly advise you to use bind variables in your code rather than building SQL statements with literals.

Comment: In fact, this is only sample code to illustrate the problem. Under the hood, in my app, I am using an ORM tool (I checked issued queries with a profiler) which issues parameterized queries and because these are tables with one to many relations (TablaAdicional => CamposAdicionales), the indices exists on the appropriate fields in order to define the relation...Any other ideas ?...Thank you...

Comment: That's probably a question for a different thread (or a total rewrite of this one if you'd prefer).  We'd need to know the actual tables involved, the query plan, data volumes, what indexes are available, etc.

Comment: I edit my question adding more information about the tables involved and the dump from sql developer. Sorry if I posted too long info, because this is my first post on stackoverflow...

Comment: It seems that obviously the problem is not the volume of records or malformed tables structure.

Comment: We still need the query and the query plan-- you've said that the actual query involves multiple tables not just the single table query you posted in your example.  If you could format your SQL (like you did for the C# code) that would make it much more readable

Comment: It is not needed an actual query with relations between tables in order to detect the problem. The app uses relations between tables, but what I did in SQL Developer was a plain: select * from "CamposAdicionales" where "TablaAdicional" = 5 simulating the relation. No more is needed in order to detect the problem. It took 9 seconds to complete. Where I get the query plan ? In SQL Developer ?

Comment: OK.  What was the query plan?  Was it using the index on `TablaAdicional`?

Comment: I work more on MS SQL Server. How I get the query plan in Oracle ?

Comment: In SQL Developer, it's a button right after the "Run Statement" and "Run Script" buttons in the toolbar.  That produces an image, though, which isn't always the easiest thing to post here.  I'd fire up SQL*Plus, do `set autotrace on` and run the query-- that produces a text-based plan that is much easier to upload in addition to query execution statistics.